# get_terms() returns Trying to get property of non-object error for custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-taxonomy, array, terms

Created custom post type and now I'm trying to create a custom taxonomy. Once I create it and try to access it with get_terms() I get an error of `non-object`. Var_dump is giving me an empty array `object(WP_Error)[1279]
  public 'errors' => 
    array (size=1)
      'invalid_taxonomy' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'Invalid taxonomy.' (length=17)
  public 'error_data' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty`

Here is the code:

```
// Custom Post Type for Use Cases page slider

function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'use_cases',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Use Cases' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Use_Case' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
             'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail'),
             'hierarchical' => true,
      'has_archive' => true
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
// Custom taxonomy for CPT
function custom_taxonomies() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Types',
        'singular_name' => 'Type',
        'search_items' => 'Search Types',
        'all_items' => 'All Types',
        'parent_item' => 'Parent Type',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Type:',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Type',
        'update_item' => 'Update Type',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Custom Type',
        'new_item_name' => 'New Type Name',
        'menu_name' => 'Type'
    );
    $args = array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'type')
    );

    register_taxonomy('type', array('use_cases'), $args);
}

add_action('init', 'custom_taxonomies');


// Shortcode for Use Cases caption

add_shortcode('Use_Case', 'use_case_shortcode_query');
function use_case_shortcode_query($atts, $content){
  extract(shortcode_atts(array( // a few default values
   'posts_per_page' => '11',
   'post_type' => 'use_cases',
        )
   , $atts));

  global $post;

  $posts = new WP_Query(array( // a few default values
   'posts_per_page' => '11',
   'post_type' => 'use_cases'
        ));
    //print_r($posts);
  $output = '';
$out = '';
    if ($posts->have_posts()):
        while ($posts->have_posts()):
                    //echo var_dump($posts->the_post());
            $posts->the_post();
            /*$out .= '<div class="use_case_boxes">
                <h4>Name: <a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="' . get_the_title() . '">'.get_the_title() .'</a></h4>
                <p class="Film_desc">'.get_the_content().'</p>';
                // add here more...*/
                                $out .= '<a href='.get_post_meta($post->ID, "location", true).'><div class="vce-row vce-element--has-background vce-row--col-gap-30 use_case_finance vce-row-equal-height vce-row-columns--top vce-row-content--top" id="el-6cc8dbe6" data-vce-do-apply="all el-6cc8dbe6"><div class="vce-content-background-container"></div><div class="vce-row-content" data-vce-element-content="true"><div class="vce-col vce-col--md-100p vce-col--xs-1 vce-col--xs-last vce-col--xs-first vce-col--sm-last vce-col--sm-first vce-col--md-last vce-col--lg-last vce-col--xl-last vce-col--md-first vce-col--lg-first vce-col--xl-first" id="el-f4a5f49c" data-vce-do-apply="background el-f4a5f49c"><div class="vce-col-inner" data-vce-element-content="true" data-vce-do-apply="padding margin  border el-f4a5f49c"><div class="vce-row-container"><div class="vce-row vce-row--col-gap-30 vce-row-columns--top vce-row-content--top" id="el-356c02e5" data-vce-do-apply="all el-356c02e5"><div class="vce-row-content" data-vce-element-content="true"><div class="vce-col vce-col--md-100p vce-col--xs-1 vce-col--xs-last vce-col--xs-first vce-col--sm-last vce-col--sm-first vce-col--md-last vce-col--lg-last vce-col--xl-last vce-col--md-first vce-col--lg-first vce-col--xl-first" id="el-4c08b71e" data-vce-do-apply="background el-4c08b71e"><div class="vce-col-inner" data-vce-element-content="true" data-vce-do-apply="padding margin  border el-4c08b71e"><div class="vce-row-container"><div class="vce-row vce-row--col-gap-30 vce-row-columns--top vce-row-content--top" id="el-86253324" data-vce-do-apply="all el-86253324"><div class="vce-row-content" data-vce-element-content="true"><div class="vce-col vce-col--md-100p vce-col--xs-1 vce-col--xs-last vce-col--xs-first vce-col--sm-last vce-col--sm-first vce-col--md-last vce-col--lg-last vce-col--xl-last vce-col--md-first vce-col--lg-first vce-col--xl-first" id="el-a1c3851f" data-vce-do-apply="background el-a1c3851f"><div class="vce-col-inner" data-vce-element-content="true" data-vce-do-apply="padding margin  border el-a1c3851f"><div class="vce-google-fonts-heading vce-google-fonts-heading--align-center vce-google-fonts-heading--color-b-72-72-72--45--5C00FF--FF7200"><div class="vce-google-fonts-heading-wrapper"><div class="vce-google-fonts-heading--background vce" id="el-5c7b806f" data-vce-do-apply="border background  padding margin el-5c7b806f"><h2 class="vce-google-fonts-heading-inner" style="font-family: " open="" sans";="" font-weight:="" 400;"="">'.get_the_title().'</h2></div></div></div><div class="vce-single-image-container vce-single-image--align-center"><div class="vce vce-single-image-wrapper" id="el-9632dafd" data-vce-do-apply="all el-9632dafd"><figure><div class="vce-single-image-inner"><img class="vce-single-image" src="http://ai.crafts-world.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Second-home-page-design-Recovered_03.png" data-img-src="http://ai.crafts-world.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Second-home-page-design-Recovered_03.png" alt="" title="Second-home-page-design-Recovered_03"></div></figure></div></div><div class="vce-google-fonts-heading vce-google-fonts-heading--align-center vce-google-fonts-heading--color-empty--45--5C00FF--FF7200"><div class="vce-google-fonts-heading-wrapper"><div class="vce-google-fonts-heading--background vce" id="el-8f301bd3" data-vce-do-apply="border background  padding margin el-8f301bd3"><div class="vce-google-fonts-heading-inner" style="font-family: " open="" sans";="" font-weight:="" 300;"="">'.get_the_content().'</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></a></a>';

            $out .='</div>';
    /* these arguments will be available from inside $content
        get_permalink()
        get_the_content()
        get_the_category_list(', ')
        get_the_title()
        and custom fields
        get_post_meta($post->ID, 'field_name', true);
    */
    endwhile;
  else:
    return; // no posts found
endif;
  wp_reset_query();
  return html_entity_decode($out);
}

add_filter('acf/settings/remove_wp_meta_box', '__return_false');

// Add metabox for Use Cases CPT to display URL of each box.

function add_event_metaboxes() {
    add_meta_box(
        'use_case_metabox',
        'URL for Use Case Box',
        'wpt_events_location',
        'use_cases',
        'side',
        'default'

    );
}

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_event_metaboxes' );

/**
 * Output the HTML for the metabox.
 */
function wpt_events_location() {
    global $post;
    // Nonce field to validate form request came from current site
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'event_fields' );
    // Get the location data if it's already been entered
    $location = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'location', true );
    // Output the field
    echo '<input type="text" name="location" value="' . esc_textarea( $location )  . '" class="widefat">';
}


/**
 * Save the metabox data
 */
function wpt_save_events_meta( $post_id, $post ) {
    // Return if the user doesn't have edit permissions.
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    // Verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
    // because save_post can be triggered at other times.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['location'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['event_fields'], basename(__FILE__) ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    // Now that we're authenticated, time to save the data.
    // This sanitizes the data from the field and saves it into an array $events_meta.
    $events_meta['location'] = esc_textarea( $_POST['location'] );
    // Cycle through the $events_meta array.
    // Note, in this example we just have one item, but this is helpful if you have multiple.
    foreach ( $events_meta as $key => $value ) :
        // Don't store custom data twice
        if ( 'revision' === $post->post_type ) {
            return;
        }
        if ( get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, false ) ) {
            // If the custom field already has a value, update it.
            update_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $value );
        } else {
            // If the custom field doesn't have a value, add it.
            add_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $value);
        }
        if ( ! $value ) {
            // Delete the meta key if there's no value
            delete_post_meta( $post_id, $key );
        }
    endforeach;
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpt_save_events_meta', 1, 2 );




?>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
    <li class="active">
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#all">All</a>
    </li>
    <?php foreach($use_case_categories as $use_case_category) { ?>
        <li>
            <a href="#<?php echo $use_case_category->slug ?>" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $use_case_category->name ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>

<div class="tab-pane active" id="all">
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'use_cases',
        'posts_per_page' -1,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    $all_films = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>

    <?php if ( $all_films->have_posts() ) : // make sure we have films to show before doing anything?>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
            <?php while ( $all_films->have_posts() ) : $all_films->the_post(); ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php the_post_thumbnail() ?></td>
                <td><h3><?php the_title() ?></h3</td>
                <td>
                    <p class="lead"><?php the_excerpt() ?></p>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Read more</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_query() ?>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

</div><!-- all films tab pane -->


<?php foreach($use_case_categories as $use_case_category) { ?>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="<?php echo $use_case_category->slug ?>">
        <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'use_cases',
            'posts_per_page' -1,
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $use_case_category->slug
                )
            )
        );
        $films = new WP_Query( $args );
        ?>

        <?php if ( $films->have_posts() ) : // make sure we have films to show before doing anything?>
        <table class="table">
            <?php while ( $films->have_posts() ) : $films->the_post(); ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php the_post_thumbnail() ?></td>
                <td><h3><?php the_title() ?></h3</td>
                <td>
                    <p class="lead"><?php the_excerpt() ?></p>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Read more</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_query() ?>
        </table>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear: `Invalid taxonomy.`.

You're hooking to `init` to register your custom taxonomy, however you're calling `get_terms( 'type' )` right away, before `init` is fired and therefore before your taxonomy is registered.

You can't call `get_terms( 'type' )` before `init`.

Comment: What is another good hook other than `init` then?

Comment: `init` is just fine and the recommended hook. Just don't do anything before `init`.

Comment: I moved my taxonomy code with the hook up and the get_terms() is now called after taxonomy register. However, I still get the same problem. I updated my post with full code to be more clear.

Comment: `get_terms()` isn't being used at all in your post anymore.